# Computer can't read character outside utf-8 ( When I download/upload a file on the PC, it is unable to interpret characters that are Norwegian)

Tags: windows, file, utf-8, character

I've tried changing the utf-8 characters in the control panel, and changing the language to English or back to Norwegian to see if that makes a difference.

When I search online, I get the same answer every time: Go to control panel -> change language, etc.

[image]

Everyone gives the same answer and I'm not getting anywhere trying to change anything here:

[image]

Comment: 1. This doesn't seem to be related to programming, so you're asking on the wrong site. Maybe [SU] could help. 2. There really aren't any characters "outside utf-8" (excluding private use characters) 3. this seems like *something* along the way simply made a mistake and the character is wrongly encoded now, so no setting will fix it now. 4. *if* you decide to ask this elsewhere, it would **really** help to show where this string is shown, what program you're using and where that file/string came from.

Comment: Do not link important stuffs in external links (and prefer not to use images). For sure I would not open random links from random people. In any case; UTF-8 is an encoding of Unicode, and Unicode by design incorporated nearly all public encodings that existed before 1994 (and now it is including more and more characters). You should known the meaning of your data (the metadata). Else guesses are difficult and it requires a lot of try and error (so very difficult to answer). Try to get information about your file format/encoding.

Comment: Please [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code. Post a hexadecimal dump in case of (partially) binary content.

Comment: Apologies if you have already tried this, but - can you create an empty `New Text Document.txt` file, and then rename it to something which contains all the Norwegian-specific alphabet characters? If you do that, and the file name is properly encoded and displayed on your system, then the issue is with your `*.xdp` file, and not your OS settings.

Comment: @JoachimSauer While you are correct that this question _"doesn't seem to be related to programming"_, that does not automatically make the question off topic here. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which explicitly allows questions about _"software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"_. Downloading files is frequent activity of software developers, so while this question would certainly be valid on Super User, it is also valid (and potentially useful) on SO...

Comment: @JoachimSauer ...That said, it can certainly be argued that the question should be closed because it _"Needs details or clarity"_, but that is a separate matter.

Comment: Just because every place gives you the same answer doesn't mean it's the *right* answer. In this case it might be only half the answer.